# How to pass arraylist from recyclerview to Other Activity - kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter

I'm trying to pass multiple value of arraylist, which are in recyclerview to Another Activity. But every time I get a null value or either memory location instead of values.
Here is my adapter code

```
class ContactAdapter(private var contact:List<ContactModel>, private var context: Context, private val showMenu: (Boolean) -> Unit): RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactAdapter.ContactViewHolder>() {
    private var isEnable =false
    private val itemSelected = mutableListOf<Int>()
    val myMutableContactList = ArrayList<ContactModel>()
    class ContactViewHolder(private val view: View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val linlay:LinearLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.linlay)
        val name: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.name)
        val number: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.number)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ContactViewHolder {
        val layout_ =LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.contact_list,parent,false)
        return ContactViewHolder(layout_)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ContactViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = contact[position]
        holder.name.text = item.name.toString()
        holder.number.text = item.number.toString()
        holder.linlay.setOnLongClickListener{
            selectItem(holder,item,position)
            true
        }
        holder.linlay.setOnClickListener{

            if(itemSelected.contains(position)){
              itemSelected.remove(position)

                holder.linlay.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY)
                item.isSelect = false
                if(itemSelected.isEmpty()){
                    isEnable=false
                }
            }
            else if(isEnable){
                selectItem(holder,item,position)
            }
        }}
    private fun selectItem(holder: ContactAdapter.ContactViewHolder, item: ContactModel, position: Int) {
        isEnable = true
        itemSelected.add(position)
        item.isSelect = true
        showMenu(true)
        holder.linlay.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW)
        if(item.isSelect){
            myMutableContactList.add(item)}
        else{
            myMutableContactList.remove(item)}}

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return contact.size
    }
    fun sendSelectedItem(){
        if(itemSelected.isNotEmpty()){
            val intent = Intent(context,HomeActivity::class.java)
            intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("key",myMutableContactList)
            context.startActivity(intent)
            isEnable = false
            itemSelected.clear()
        } }}
```

Value is passed after selecting multiple items and the button for next activity is in the menu bar.
I'm using getter setter model class instead  of the data class
here is my model class

```
class ContactModel() :Parcelable {
    var name: String? = null
    var number: String? = null
    var isSelect: Boolean = false
    constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this() {
        name = parcel.readString()
        number = parcel.readString()
        isSelect = parcel.readByte() != 0.toByte()
    }
    fun setNames(name: String) {
        this.name = name
    }
    fun getNumbers(): String {
        return number.toString()
    }
    fun setNumbers(number: String) {
        this.number = number
    }
    fun getNames(): String {
        return name.toString()
    }
```

code of other activity

```
  private var list_: ArrayList<ContactModel>? = null
  list_ = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("key") 
         val contactModel = ContactModel()
        val name = contactModel.getName()
        val number =  contactModel.getNumbers()
        list_!!.add(contactModel)
        Log.d("name>>", name + "  " + number)
        Toast.makeText(this, name.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea but not sure is best practice or not. You can create a companion object in the activity where you want to send the data and in the companion object create a variable of type lateinit var. You can initialize it even when activity is not active from the adapter.

Comment: Definitely not best practice. That's an incorrect use of `lateinit` where nullability would make more sense. And it would prevent you from cleaning up the memory when you're done with it. Even if you changed it to be nullable, the onus is now on you to manage the cleanup and manually prevent memory leaks, and you'd have to do it across two classes instead of just one.

Comment: Thanks brother, I was also thinking the same. I was thinking, using repository pattern makes sense in this case. What you say? @Tenfour04

Answer (score 0):

If you read the documentation of this function, it says:

> The name must include a package prefix, for example the app com.android.contacts would use names like "com.android.contacts.ShowAll".

which you did not do, since you're simply using "key".

You should not have a bunch of "get" and "set" functions in your class that redundantly manage your properties. "getter" and "setter" functions are not used in Kotlin because properties fill that role.

Your Parcelable class is lacking a `CREATOR` function and a `writeToParcel` function, so it cannot work. You should consider using the [Parcelize plugin](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/parcelize) so you don't have to add those yourself.